# Swiftui - Fetch data after login

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui, firebase-authentication

I'm starting to learn SwiftUI and i'm looking for better solution to fetch user data after successful login.

For example, i need to see if the user has the account blocked or not after login

For this i have create struct in Users.swift

```
struct Users: Identifiable, Codable{

    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var Societe : String
    var Nom : String
    var Prenom : String
    var HasBlocked : Bool
    var SiteID : [String]
    var Poste : String
    var Email : String
}
```

and firebase class in Firebase.swift

```
class Firebase: ObservableObject {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var viewRouter: ViewRouter
    @Published var user : Users? = nil

    private var db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    
        func fetchData() {
            db.collection("Users").document(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).addSnapshotListener{ (snapshot, error) in
                guard let documents = snapshot?.data() else {
                    print("No documents")
                    return
                }
                let name = documents["Nom"] as? String ?? ""
                let surname = documents["Prenom"] as? String ?? ""
                let email = documents["Email"] as? String ?? ""
                let societe = documents["Societe"] as? String ?? ""
                let poste = documents["Poste"] as? String ?? ""
                let siteId = documents["SiteID"] as? [String] ?? []
                let hasBlocked = documents["HasBlocked"] as? Bool ?? true
                
                if let user = self.user?.SiteID{
                    print(user)
                }else{
                    print("no document2")
                }
                
                self.user = Users(Societe: societe, Nom: name, Prenom: surname, HasBlocked: hasBlocked, SiteID: siteId, Poste: poste, Email: email)
                }
        }
}
```

and in the SignInView after press login button, i call func signInUser

```
@ObservedObject private var firebase = Firebase()

func signInUser(userEmail: String, userPassword: String) {
        
        signInProcessing = true
        
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { authResult, error in
        
            guard error == nil else {
                signInProcessing = false
                signInErrorMessage = error!.localizedDescription
                return
            }
            switch authResult {
            case .none:
                print("Could not sign in user.")
                signInProcessing = false
            case .some(_):
                print("User signed in")

                // get data and check ??

                signInProcessing = false
                withAnimation {
                    viewRouter.currentPage = .homePage
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But i don't know how to fetch data after login for check if the account has blocked and then pass the data to Homeview without re-fetch data to optimize call database.

thank for your help

Comment: Firestore does provide async implementations use those and restructure your code. A good tutorial would be: https://peterfriese.dev/posts/firebase-async-calls-swift/

Comment: What is the question? At first glance the code in fetchData looks pretty good to me and you would simply call that in the closure following the `signIn` function. If there's an error, handle it, otherwise get the logged in user from authResult like this `guard let user = authResult?.user`, then call your function. Is there something else?

Comment: Once user is login, I would like to retrieve the user data stored on the database with his id but the fetch data is async and i want to check if user has account blocked before going to next view. I need to wait for the complete return of fetchData() before moving to the next view.

Comment: Well, you've got all of the tools you need! 1) User authenticates  2) Within the closure, read firebase and see if the account is blocked. 3) Within that firebase read closure, if blocked do not proceed to next view. If not blocked, process to next view. That code flow is perfectly fine since you're going to the next step within each closure.

Comment: Look into `@FirestoreQuery` for the snapshot part and you can set your rules in the Firestore to not let `read` per your case. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me address this at a high level as your code seems fine but its's just wrapping your brain around the asynchronous calls.

I am pretty sure you have everything you need - here's the flow using pseudo code

```
authenticate { auth closure
    read user document using auth.uid { snapshot closure
         if snapshot has user blocked {
            do not proceed to next view
         } else { //user is not blocked
            proceed to next view
         }
    }
}
```

Remember that Firebase data is only valid within the closure following the Firebase call and if you follow the above pseudo code, it does just that...

```
auth closure - has valid firebase auth information so you can get the uid

    snapshot closure  - has valid snapshot info so you can see if the user is blocked
    
        the If statement will then determine the next thing to do - either don't show
           the view if blocked or show it if not blocked
```

So borrowing from your code

```
func signInUser(userEmail: String, userPassword: String) {
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { authResult, error in
             db.collection("Users").document(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).getDocument {
                  either go to next view or not
```

Note that you should be using getDocument in this case to read the document once instead of adding a listener.

Comment: You're right, I was focused on async.
it works as I wanted.
thank you so much !!!!